# Trouble using EXEC Command in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Apparently there is a syntax error when i try to use the exec command to call parameter var's for table names.

Here's my code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[createTable] 
    @tblName varchar(30), 
    @tblSTDColumns int = 0,
    @dupExistTblName varchar(60) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @dupExistTblName = @tblName + '_COPY'   

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
               WHERE table_name LIKE @tblName)
    (       
        EXEC('SELECT * INTO [' + @dupExistTblName + '] FROM [' + @tblName + '] WHERE 1=2')      
    )

    EXEC('DROP TABLE ['+ @tblName + ']')

    EXEC('SELECT * INTO [' + @tblName + '] FROM [' + @dupExistTblName] + ' WHERE 1=2')
END
```

The line `EXEC('SELECT * INTO [' + @dupExistTblName + '] FROM [' + @tblName + '] WHERE 1=2')` generates a syntax error

Comment: Care to share the syntax error message?

Comment: Do you know about the PRINT command?

Comment: Last EXEC should be `EXEC('SELECT * INTO [' + @tblName + '] FROM [' + @dupExistTblName + '] WHERE 1=2')`

Comment: Post the full error message as well as print the statement too

Comment: Be careful here. You should be wrapping the table names inside of QUOTENAME to help prevent sql injection. You also should probably be checking where table_name = @tblName or you might get a false positive.

Comment: You can't do string concatenation inside EXEC call.

Comment: hey thanks for the downvote! I love loosing the ability to ask questions on this site! such a cool function for us newbies! so cool to be around people who were never n00bs b4, will make me such a better coder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing some things, and misplacing others.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[createTable] 

    @tblName varchar(30), 
    @tblSTDColumns int = 0,
    @dupExistTblName varchar(60) = ''


AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @dupExistTblName = @tblName+'_COPY' 

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_name like @tblName)
BEGIN     
    EXEC('SELECT * INTO [' + @dupExistTblName + '] FROM [' + @tblName + '] WHERE 1=2')      
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    EXEC('DROP TABLE ['+ @tblName + ']')
    EXEC('SELECT * INTO [' + @tblName + '] FROM [' + @dupExistTblName + '] WHERE 1=2')
END

END
```

Comment: Why do that? Can't he just use the ID and avoid using SQL inserts? Especially since you so nakedly do not qualify your variables.

Answer (score 0):

**A)** MSDN states this on every relevant page:

> Validate all user input. Do not concatenate user input before you
>   validate it. Never execute a command constructed from unvalidated user
>   input.

**B)** `IF` statements in `TSQL` only work on the next proceeding query/command line in `SQL`. Using `BEGIN END` is a good way of ensuring proper execution. Your style of course, but being explicit is preferred.

**C)** Declaring variables between `CREATE`/`ALTER` and `AS BEGIN` imply you want those variables to have user input. (`@dupExistTblName`) is immediately replaced?

Below is one method that includes a style of security with the added bonus of `RAISERROR` to prevent fatal errors and provide feedback.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[createTable] 
    @tblName varchar(30)
--    @tblSTDColumns int = 0
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(255);
    IF OBJECT_ID(@tblName) IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
        DECLARE @dupExistTblName varchar(60);
        SET @dupExistTblName = @tblName + '_COPY';
            BEGIN
            SET @string = N'SELECT * INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@dupExistTblName) + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tblName) + ' WHERE 1=2';
            --SELECT @string
            EXEC (@string);
            END
        END
    ELSE
    -- no need for a fatal error from trying to input a bad table name.
    RAISERROR('Unknown Error. You Entered: %s. Check syntax.'
                , 10
                , 1
                , @tblName)
END

EXEC dbo.createTable @tblName = 'MyNAMEST'
```

> Unknown Error. You Entered: MyNAMEST. Check syntax.

To add further protections, MSDN promotes use of `sp_executesql` which allows for caching of SQL statement themselves. There many different ways to write, such as the following:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT * INTO QUOTENAME(@TblcopyName) 
                     FROM QUOTENAME(@tbleName) WHERE 1 = 2'
                   , N'@TblcopyName NVARCHAR(50), @tbleName NVARCHAR(50)'
                   , @TblcopyName = @dupExistTblName
                   , @tblName = @tblName
```

Comment: OBJECT_ID, OBJECT_NAME, SCHEMA_ID, and SCHEMA_NAME can be used here if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with! Thanks everyone!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[createTable] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @tblName varchar(30), 
    @dupExistTblName varchar(60) = ''
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @dupExistTblName = @tblName+'_COPY' 
    PRINT @tblName + '-tbl name     ' + @dupExistTblName
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_name like @tblName)

        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRY
            EXEC('SELECT * INTO [' + @dupExistTblName + '] FROM [' + @tblName + '] WHERE 1=2')
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
            END CATCH
            EXEC('DROP TABLE ['+ @tblName + ']')
            PRINT 'TABLE DROPPED'
            EXEC('SELECT * INTO [' + @tblName + '] FROM [' + @dupExistTblName + '] WHERE 1=2')
        END
END
```